# Survival Analysis tools in Python

Tags: python, survival, mortality

I am wondering if there are any packages for python that is capable of performing survival analysis. I have been using the survival package in R but would like to port my work to python.

Comment: Use Rpy to call R from Python ;-)

Comment: It is exceedingly doubtful that the Python developers for survival analysis have put into the effort anywhere near what Terry Therneau and others have put into the R survival package in the past 30 years, including extensive testing. The survival package undergoes the most rigorous testing procedures I've seen in statistics.

Comment: Agreed. R's `survival` package is under close scrutiny by a large community.

Comment: RPy (2 now) is very painful to install in my experience.

Comment: meanwhile, you can easily call python from within R

Answer (score 23, accepted):

AFAIK, there aren't any survival analysis packages in python. As mbq comments above, the only route available would be to [Rpy](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/).

Even if there were a pure python package available, I would be very careful in using it, in particular I would look at:

- How often does it get updated.
- Does it have a large user base?
- Does it have advanced techniques?

One of the benefits of R, is that these standard packages get a massive amount of testing and user feed back. When dealing with real data, unexpected edge cases can creep in.

Comment: In the last 5 years many things changed (for better) for Python. Vide [answer by Cam.Davidson.Pilon](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/69484/6552) on [Lifelines](http://lifelines.readthedocs.org/).

Answer (score 73):

Check out the [*lifelines*](https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/lifelines)¹ project for a simple and clean implementation of survival models in Python, including

- Estimators of survival functions
- Estimators of cumulative hazard curves
- Cox's proportional hazard regression model
- Cox's time varying regression model
- parametric AFT models
- Aalen's additive regression model
- Multivariate testing

Benefits:

- built on top of Pandas
- pure Python & easy to install
- built in plotting functions
- simple interface

Documentation is available here: [documentation and examples](http://lifelines.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#)

Example usage:

```
from lifelines import KaplanMeierFitter

survival_times = np.array([0., 3., 4.5, 10., 1.])
events = np.array([False, True, True, False, True])

kmf = KaplanMeierFitter()
kmf.fit(survival_times, event_observed=events)

print(kmf.survival_function_)
print(kmf.median_)
kmf.plot()
```

Example plots from the built-in plotting library:

[image]

1. Disclaimer: I'm the main author. Ping me (email in profile) for questions or feedback about *lifelines*.

Comment: (+1) Pretty clever name for a survival package.

Answer (score 9):

[python-asurv](http://sourceforge.net/projects/python-asurv/) is an effort to port the [asurv](http://www.astrostatistics.psu.edu/statcodes/sc_censor.html) software for survival methods in astronomy.   Might be worth keeping an eye on, but cgillespie is right about the things to watch out for: it has a *long* way to go and development doesn't seem active.  (AFAICT only one method exists and even completed, the package may be lacking for, say, biostatisticians.)

You're probably better off using [survival](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/index.html) package in R from Python through something like [RPy](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2.html) or [PypeR](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v35/c02).  I haven't had any problems doing this myself.

Answer (score 8):

[PyIMSL](http://www.vni.com/campaigns/pyimslstudioeval/) contains a handful of routines for survival analyses. It is Free As In Beer for noncommercial use, fully supported otherwise. From the documentation in the Statistics User Guide...

Computes Kaplan-Meier estimates of survival 
probabilties:  kaplanMeierEstimates()

Analyzes survival and reliability data using Cox’s
proportional hazards model: propHazardsGenLin()

Analyzes survival data using the generalized 
linear model:  survivalGlm()

Estimates using various parametric modes:  survivalEstimates()

Estimates a reliability hazard function using a
nonparametric approach:  nonparamHazardRate()

Produces population and cohort life tables:  lifeTables()

Answer (score 5):

You can now use R from within [IPython](http://ipython.org), so you might want to look into using IPython with the R extension.

Comment: Can you give an example of this? I'm curious to try it out!

Comment: I believe you refer to [R magic](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/extensions/rmagic.html) interface (which uses `rpy2`). I too would love to see a quick example. (It is my understanding that survival models are not yet fully available in [statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/).)

Comment: I'm not too sure about statsmodels, but you can get notebooks from github with examples of the C, Octave and [R](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/docs/examples/notebooks/rmagic_extension.ipynb) extensions. You need to run the Notebook to use them obviously, but I'm sure you can use the same code in any interface.

Comment: @user603 Here is a simple demo: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/4383682/ ; this relies on fairly recent iPython, I believe.

Answer (score 5):

I also want to mention [scikit-survival](http://github.com/sebp/scikit-survival), which provides models for survival analysis that can be easily combined with tools from scikit-learn (e.g. KFold cross-validation).

As of this writing, [scikit-survival](http://github.com/sebp/scikit-survival) includes implementations of

- Nelson-Aalen estimator of cumulative hazard function.
- Kaplan-Meier estimator of survival function.
- Cox's proportional hazard’s model with and without elastic net penalty.
- Accelerated failure time model.
- Survival Support Vector Machine.
- Gradient boosted Cox model.
- concordance index for performance evaluation.

Comment: scikit-survival is excellent for time-to-event prediction related tasks!

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using `R` through `RPy` or equivalent there are a number of survival analysis routines in the [statsmodels](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/statsmodels) (formerly `sicpy.statsmodel`) python library. They are in the "sandbox" package though, meaning they aren't supposed to be ready for production right now.

E.g. you have the Cox model of proportional hazard coded [here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/sandbox/cox.py).